# How to put Jquery minified in Rails4 with jquery-rails gem?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, asset-pipeline, minify

i'am trying to create a super lightweight page with rails, and the jquery-rails gem wont put the minify version of jquery on final js file.

i've tryed to change my `application.js` to have `//=requry jquery.min` and other variations but nothing work.

this is my final js after compile (with jquery not minifyed):

```
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.2
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle
 ...
 "function"!=typeof Object.create&&(Object.create=function(t){function e(){}...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the Jquery is minified the problem is the Jquery is not minified by uglyfier, the Jquery-rails gem source is already minified but have a simple header commented wich causes some tools like the [PageSpeedInsights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) won't recognize as minified.

so i've made this mistake sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is for production, if you have

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
```

in your production.rb environment file, and then precompile your assets,

```
RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile
```

it will compress everything in your application.js, application.css and anything else you add to your assets pipeline which eliminates the need to find a minified version yourself. Rails does it for you.

Comment: yes i`m on production and already have the `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier` and ran the `RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile` but the jquey continues wont minifyed. ONLY jquery all other scripts are minifyed

Answer (score 1):

`rails 4.2.6` I just changed `//= require jquery` to `//= require jquery.min`

This means that you will always use the minified version regardless of environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these? (Per the official github docs)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

Comment: yes this is the default configuration of `application.js`, the jquery i get is not minyfied, only the jqurey. my final script file is only one with jquery scripts first not minified, and after that my others scrtips minified.